# Why did Java designers didn't create an error for overloaded methods with same arguments in different order?

Tags: java

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here

        Tree t = new Tree();
        t.cutTree("saw", 10);
        t.cutTree(10, "knife");

    }

    static class Tree{

        public static void cutTree(String instrument, int cutLength){
            System.out.println("first method");
        }

        public static void cutTree(int cutLength, String instrument){
            System.out.println("second method");
        }

    }
}
```

In those two overloaded methods, the arguments are same, but they are in different order.

Why is this allowed in Java?
What would have been the reasoning behind this by Java creators?

Comment: The reasoning is that each of the two method calls makes it unambiguous which method you actually want to invoke.

Comment: Why *would* this be an error?

Comment: The better question is why *should* it be an error/warning? I personally can’t think of a good reason.

Comment: There are 2 main reasons:

1. It is unambiguous which method overload is intended.
2. Just because a function overloads with the same types in a different order doesn't necessarily mean the parameters are simply transposed.

For example:

```java
public void say(string message, int times) {
  for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    System.out.println(message);
  }
}

public void say(int volume, string message) {
  if (volume > 50) {
    System.out.println(message.toUpperCase());
  } else {
    System.out.println(message.toLowerCase());
  }
}
```

Comment: I was writing an answer when this was closed as opinion based (which is sort of correct as the question is phrased, but I thought it was still interesting) so it was originally formatted better, but since I typed it all up already I figured I post it as a comment.

Comment: Ignore the parameter _names_ and consider the argument lists to be made up only of a sequence of types.  Because that's what Java actually does.  Then it's pretty clear that `cutTree(String, int)` and `cutTree(int, String)` are different method signatures.

Comment: in the same vein, what about `cutTree(int numberOfTrees, String cutPattern)` as opposed to  `cutTree(String instrument, int cutLength)`?

Comment: @curiosag In your example, the arguments are completely different and that is fine.